# What's the difference between $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{d}{d x}$?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I wonder if there is a difference between:
$$\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}, \ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x), \ \frac{d f(x)}{d x} \ \mathrm{and} \ \frac{d}{d x}f(x)$$
I saw all of them in a single demonstration and got quite confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- First of all, note that for understanding the difference between partial derivatives and total derivatives, you need to consider a function with more than one independent variable. I'm assuming a multi-variate function $f$.

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and  $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}f$ means same and they are the [partial derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative) of the function $f$ with respect to $x$.

While, $\dfrac{d f}{dx}$ and $\dfrac{d}{dx} f$ means same and they are the [derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) of the function $f$ with respect to $x$.

> The only difference between the derivative of a function and the partial derivative of a function is that, in case of partial derivatives, we have to keep all the independent variables as constants which is not to be considered in case of total derivative.

***For example:***

Let's say we have a function which is defined as $f(x, y) = 2x + 3y$

For this function, total derivative and partial derivatives w.r.t. $x$ are given by,

- $\dfrac{df(x,y)}{dx} = \dfrac{d}{dx} (2x + 3y)= \dfrac{d}{dx} (2x) + \dfrac{d}{dx}(3y) = 2 + 3\dfrac{dy}{dx}$
- $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(2x + 3y) =\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(2x)  +\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} (3y) = 2 $

In the first case, we have considered $y$ as a separate variable, and in the case of partial derivative, we have considered it as a constant.

---

In case the function has only one independent variable, then only:
$$\dfrac{d f(x)}{dx} = \dfrac{d}{dx} f(x) = \dfrac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial }{\partial x} f(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ means partial derivative of $f$ wrt  variable $x$ and it is used to indicate derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ when $f$ has more than one independent variable, for example $f(x,t)$. If $f$ has only one independent variable as in $f(x)$, $\dfrac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}=\dfrac{df(x)}{dx}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x)=\dfrac{d}{dx}f(x)$.